# Script Files not loaded in Android Webview custom renderer

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have loaded local html using Android WebView renderer. The html is loading properly. But the scripts which is referred inside html file is not loaded. The script files are located inside the assets folder.

**Render File Code**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);
                    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JellyBean)
                    {
                        webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                        webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                    }
                    SetNativeControl(webView);
                }

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {

                    Control.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Sample/index.html"); 
                }
            }
```

**Html Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head> 
  <script src="file:///android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Render -->
   <script src="file:///android_asset/epub.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">     
  var book = ePub("file:///android_asset/Sample/Azure_Cosmos_DB_and_DocumentDB_Succinctly/);
    $(document).ready(function () {   
   book.renderTo("area");
  });       
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="main">
    <div id="prev" onclick="book.prevPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">‹</div>
    <div id="area" ></div>
    <div id="next" onclick="book.nextPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">›</div>    
</div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest me to load corresponding JS files in webview rendering method?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would place your script tag at the bottom of your HTML not in the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="main">
    <div id="prev" onclick="book.prevPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">‹</div>
    <div id="area" ></div>
    <div id="next" onclick="book.nextPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">›</div>    
</div>    
    </body>
<script src="file:///android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Render -->
<script src="file:///android_asset/epub.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var book = ePub("file:///android_asset/Sample/Azure_Cosmos_DB_and_DocumentDB_Succinctly/");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        book.renderTo("area");
    });
</script>
</html>
```

You have also forgot a " at the end of `var book = ePub("file:///android_asset/Sample/Azure_Cosmos_DB_and_DocumentDB_Succinctly/");`

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your update. I have moved the script part to bottom and corrected the missing quote when call epub. Even the scripts are not rendering.

Comment: My bad I see a an other mistake now. just need to say: src="android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"  instead of src="file:///android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" the folder android_assets is located in your www folder?